# О мозаике можно сказать "переложена"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Мозаика хранит и имена своих донаторов, тех, на чьи средства было
>   создано столь дорогостоящее произведение. Однако при реставрациях и
>   переделках утрачены изображения Бога-Отца, Святого Духа
>   и двух апостолов. Важно добавить, что в XVI веке подверглись
>   реставрации, точнее, **были переложены и некоторые из существующих
>   фигур** по правой стороне; таким образом, здесь можно наблюдать
>   различие между искусством разных периодов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что так о мозаике можно говорить.

*Мозаика в храме Большой Софии. Считается, что справа и слева от Христа изображены император Константин IX и императрица Зоя. Однако надпись над головой царя явно переложена...*
[**Г. Носовский, А. Фоменко. Забытый Иерусалим**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=yDyK39tOCTsC&pg=SA1-PA26&lpg=SA1-PA26&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=UrWxvDG2n-&sig=uI1ywH1JC_UEsdmY7F8RNgX41IA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5r8rA09fYAhVGJ1AKHavbDeUQ6AEIXjAN#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false)

*С северной сто­ро­ны от ка­пел­лы со­хра­ни­лась часть т. н. Трик­ли­ния Льва III (тра­пез­ная ста­ро­го Ла­те­ран­ско­го двор­ца; 797 года, пе­ре­стро­ен в 1741-1744 годах, архитектор Ф. Фу­га; в ап­си­де - мо­заи­ка конца VIII века, пе­ре­ло­жен­ная в XVIII веке).*
[**Большая Российская энциклопедия. ЛАТЕРА́Н**](https://w.histrf.ru/articles/article/show/latieran)

*Создание мозаичного комплекса относится к эпохе Теодориха, в нём участвовали различные мастера. В 60-х годах VI века мозаики были частично переложены, чтобы изжить память об остготских правителях Равенны.*
*После этого, мозаики на арианские темы были частью переложены, частью зачернены (как гласит предание, это было сделано по требованию папы Григория Великого).*
Википедия